# How do I implement a Selector in Fluxor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluxor

I am using Fluxor to manage state in my Blazor application and I have been unable to figure out the Selector part of the process.

I currently just inject the IState into my Razor Pages and get values from the State using State.Value.MyData

This works fine in a Razor Component that inherits from Fluxor.Blazor.Web.Components.FluxorComponent but doesn't work when getting a value in a class that is not a FluxorComponent. If I inject IState into a service class the state is not updated as changes are made.
I can get around this by making transient services but I feel like I'm missing part of the puzzle here...

I think I need to use the Selector and SelectorProtocol but I have been unable to figure out how these parts are actually used in practice. Is there somewhere an example of how the Selector syntax is intended to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FluxorComponent is a convenience class that simply subscribes to all properties implementing `IState<T>` and calls `StateHasChanged` whenever one of them fires a `StateChanged` event.

You can achieve this yourself quite easily like so

```cs
@implements IDisposable

@code
{
  private IDisposable Subscription;
  [Inject] private IState<MyState> MyState { get; set; }

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    base.OnInitialized(); // Does nothing, but good practice
    Subscription = StateSubscriber.Subscribe(this, _ => InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged));
  }

  void IDisposable.Dispose()
  {
    Subscription.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add void to OnInitialized method.

protected override void OnInitialized()
  { ... }